# How can I have different display names on different sites?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Is it possible (or are there any plans to implement such feature) that allow you to have separate usernames per Stack Exchange site?

For example, on Stack Overflow I'd like to use my realname as my username, but on some of the other sites I might prefer to use an alias, so far I can't seem to do this.

I changed my Display Name on one site and it replicated to the others.

Comment: No repro here. I can have different names (and gravatars) for different sites.

Comment: Huh. I make doing this a matter of principle when active on a SE site. Never had a problem with it, but you could always just create a separate account.

Comment: `I changed my Display Name on one site and it replicated to the others.` That shouldn't have happened automatically. Are you 100% sure about this? That would be a bug

Comment: Your account on [Personal Finance and Money](http://money.stackexchange.com/users/1131/james) has a different display name and you apparently haven't touched it since last month. Do you remember how you managed to accomplish that?

Comment: Trust me, this can be done. View my profile and click the accounts tab if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is already present.

If you don't believe me, click on my profile, click the accounts tab, and note that I have a different name on here and Gaming than I do on SO and the rest of the network.

Changing your name on one site does not replicate it to other sites.

Answer (score 4):

Edit each one manually, and **DO NOT** click this button (located at the bottom of your 'Accounts' page):

[image]

It only replicates if you push the above button...Tried it myself...